# Why do fewer computers appear in "Network" with Windows 10 compared to Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10

On my network, a Windows 10 machine shows 7 other computers in the Network view of Explorer. 
A Windows 7 machine on the same network shows 11 other computers (all running Windows)

How can Windows 10 be configured to show the other Windows computers that are present?

Comment: Is there anything different about those 4 that are not shown compared to the other 7? Maybe a different Windows version?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.